# Writing to Jira6 API via Ruby (error 415)

Tags: ruby, api, http, rest, jira

I am pretty new to ruby. To be honest its my first try doing a ruby script with an http connection. I am lost at one point. Sending data via POST to Jira6. Here is the code I use

```ruby
# If issues_id.count != 0 make a transition of the issues
if issue_id.count > 0
    issue_id.each do |id|
        transition_data = '{"transition": {"id": "666"}}'

        Net::HTTP.start(jira_domain, jira_port) do |http|
            ap jira_transition + id + jira_transition_query
            request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(jira_transition + id + jira_transition_query)
            request.basic_auth jira_user, jira_pass
            request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
            ap transition_data
            request.set_form_data('data' => '{"transition": {"id": "841"}}');

            response = http.request(request)

            ap response.code
            ap response
        end
    end
end
```

testing this results in the following error:

```
#<Net::HTTPUnsupportedMediaType 415 Unsupported Media Type readbody=true> error.
```

when I try the same with curl, it works just fine

```
curl -D- -u external_user:external_pass -X POST --data '{"transition": {"id": "841"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira.demo.com:80/rest/api/2/issue/17399/transitions\?expand\=transitions.fields
```

Just to be sure I don't get the same crap answers like on google groups:
Yes I reseted the issue after a sucessfull try :-) 
Yes the transitionId 841 is correct :-)

Can someone please send me in the right direction howto send the data to Jira6 REST-API? I think its a marginal error, but I do not recognize it.
Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try the [jira-ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby)

Comment: jira-ruby gem is broken. Everytime I try this I get some complie errors originating in the bundle.

Comment: Compile errors don't necessarily mean the gem is broken.  I've used is successfully.  Maybe post some of the errors to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. For some reason, you can not use 'request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"'. You must create a new header variable and then pass it as a second argument to Post.new. Then use request.body to include the update params.

```
if issue_id.count > 0
    issue_id.each do |id|
        transition_data = '{"transition": {"id": "666"}}'

        Net::HTTP.start(jira_domain, jira_port) do |http|
            ap jira_transition + id + jira_transition_query
            header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(jira_transition + id + jira_transition_query, header)
            request.basic_auth jira_user, jira_pass
            #request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
            ap transition_data
            #request.set_form_data('data' => '{"transition": {"id": "841"}}');
            params = {transistion: {id: 841}}
            request.body = params.to_json

            response = http.request(request)

            ap response.code
            ap response
        end
    end
end
```